# Cannot import webdriverwait from selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am a new programmer and recently trying to send a WhatsApp message using selenium but it always shows cannot import name 'webdriverwait' from 'selenium.webdrivr.support.ui'

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebdriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.support import Select
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   import time
```

and it shows following Importerror

```
   ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-1-34e812ae7ecd> in <module>
         1 from selenium import webdriver
   ----> 2 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebdriverWait
         3 from selenium.webdriver.support import Select
         4 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
         5 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    mportError: cannot import name 'WebdriverWait' from 'selenium.webdriver.support.ui' 
   (C:\Users\siddh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\ui.py)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please note that it is ```WebDriverWait```  you have a lowercase ```d```.  from : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 1):

As ewong said, you are importing the wrong thing. `WebDriverWait` is what you want. Python, like all other programming languages, is case-sensitive.

Replace:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebdriverWait
```

With:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the imports that work for me. The only difference between mine and @Unsigned_Arduino are that I uses an `alias` for some of my `class` names. 
**IMPORTS**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as DriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as DriverConditions
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it too late, I just try to help. Try to use

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

its worked for me